# Different Seeds under one Startup

Tags: c#, .net-core

Here's the case: I have a method:

```
public startic class ServiceFactory
{
   public static void IWebHostBuilder Foo()
   {
      return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
             .UseEnvironment("someEnv")
             .UseStartup<SomeStartup>()
             .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
   }
}
```

Inside `SomeStartup` I would like to customize DB seed based on method/test case requirements.
**My intention is not to add an additional seed on the pile of already existing seeds but creating a brand new pile for each set of tests.**
I haven't find any appropriate extension method that would help nor a way to parameterize `SomeStartup`

Test case example is below:

```
{
//Arrange
   var context = new bar(_someParameter1, ServiceFactory.Foo(), someParameter2)
//Act
   (...)
//Assert
   (...)
}
```

Do you have any sugestions?

Comment: I think you would have to put into the constructor for the SomeStartup class.

Comment: ```.UseStartup<SomeStartup>()``` won't let me use a class with injected parameter

Comment: Add a setting to select the seed. In `Startup.ConfigureService`, you can inject `IConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use environment variables as usual? Add IHostingEnvironment to Configure method in SomeStartup analyze the environment:

```
public void Configure(IHostingEnvironment env, ... )
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
// seed1
        }
        else
        {
// seed2
        }
// or like this    
        if (!env.IsEnvironment("EF_MIGRATIONS"))
        {
// seed3                       
        }
    // or some other variable
    var p = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH");
    // 
    seed4
    // ... 
}
```